# assign an element of a structure for whole vector of structures?

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming, assign

Can I do assigning as shawn below **without making new assigment functions**?

```
struct S
{
  int     one;
  double  two;
}

vector< S > v( 10 );

std::transform( begin( v ), end( v ), begin( v ), /*some how bind S::two to 10., for example*/ );
```

result: all `v` elements have `S:two` == 10, `S::one`'s have the values they had before `std::transform`

No C++11, boost is allowed.

Comment: You seem to use C++11 already. You've implemented free begin/end functions yourself? What is `structure` BTW?

Comment: ``begin / end`` are just for more readability, I use VS2008

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a generic `setter` using which you could *set* **any** member of a struct.

For example, if you want to set the member `two` to a particular value `10.0`, then you have to write this:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), make_setter(&S::two, 10.0));
```

And you're done.

Here is the implementation of `setter` and `make_setter`:

```
template<typename C, typename M>
class setter
{
     M C::*m_member;   
     M m_value;

public:

     setter(M C::*member, M value) : m_member(member), m_value(value) {}

     C operator()(C item)
     {
         item.*m_member = m_value;
         return item;
     }
};

template<typename C, typename M>
setter<C, M> make_setter(M C::*member, M value) 
{
    return setter<C,M>(member, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if I just use offset of an element? Like ``std::fill( &v[0] + offsetoff(element), &v[0] + offsetoff(element) + N, value )``? I have a ``POD`` structure.

Comment: @fogbit: That will not work. Think how `fill` works, and what you're passing to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct set_two {
    double v;
    set_two(double v_) : v(v_) { }
    S operator()(S s) const { 
        s.two=v;
        return s;
    }
};

std::transform( begin(v), end(v), begin(v), set_two(10.0) );
```

Although I assume your `begin` and `end` are you own because otherwise it's from boost or C++11